# Ruby hexacode to unicode conversion

Tags: ruby, unicode

I crawled a website which contains unicode, an the results look something like, if in code

a = "\\u2665  \\uc624 \\ube60! \\uc8fd \\uae30 \\uc804 \\uc5d0"

May I know how do I do it in Ruby to convert it back to the original Unicode text which is in UTF-8 format?

Comment: Or shall I focus on remove the double slash and replace it to single ?

Comment: It would help for you to add a small sample of the code you use to your original question. Show code to connect to the site, retrieve content, extract a string and display it.

Comment: to be sure, you can print out "a.bytes.to_a". if the first few bytes are [92, 117, 50, 54, 54..., you have ASCII data that has to be converted (or just downloaded differently). if the first few are [226, 153, 165, 32, 236..., you actually have Unicode data, it's just not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ruby 1.9, you can try:

```
a.force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Otherwise if you have < 1.9, I'd suggest reading [this article](http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/) on converting to UTF-8 in Ruby 1.8.

Comment: Sorry for some reason the double backslash didn't appear, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: you should be able to 'puts a', and see the string printed out. for me, at least, I can print out that string in both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2

long answer:
First thing: it depends on if you're using ruby 1.8.7, or 1.9.2, since the way strings and encodings were handled changed.

in 1.8.7:
strings are just lists of bytes. when you print them out, if your OS can handle it, you can just 'puts a' and it should work correctly. if you do a[0], you'll get the first *byte*. if you want to get each character, things are pretty darn tricky.

in 1.9.2
strings are lists of bytes, with an encoding. If the webpage was sent with the correct encoding, your string should already be encoded correctly. if not, you'll have to set it (as per Mike Lewis's answer). if you do a[0], you'll get the first *character* (the heart). if you want each byte, you can do a.bytes.

Comment: I am pretty sure my OS handles it, it's OS X Snow Leopard anyway. when I do puts a, this is what I get 
\u2665 \uc624\ube60! \uc8fd\uae30\uc804\uc5d0 and a.inspect gives me
"\"\\\\u2665 \\\\uc624\\\\ube60! \\\\uc8fd\\\\uae30\\\\uc804\\\\uc5d0\""

Answer (score 1):

If your OS, for whatever reason, is giving you *those literal ascii characters*,my previous answer is obviously invalid, disregard it. :P

here's what you can do:

```
a.gsub(/\\u([a-z0-9]+)/){|p| [$1.to_i(16)].pack("U")}
```

this will scan for the ascii string '\u' followed by a hexadecimal number, and replace it with the correct unicode character.

Comment: Caveat: if you have a string that includes a literal backslash followed by `u` and four hex digits, you've probably not parsed something right. This is often a result of trying to deal with JSON string literals as strings instead of consuming them with a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the encoding when you open a new `IO` object: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000889

Compared to Mike's solution, this may prevent troubles if you forget to force the encoding before exposing the string to the rest of your application, if there are multiple mechanisms for retrieving strings from your module or class. However, if you begin crawling SJIS or KOI-8 encoded websites, then Mike's solution will be easier to adapt for the character encoding name returned by the web server in its headers.